# Generators of $su(2) \oplus su(2)$ in the $(A, B)$ representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, group-representations, poincare-symmetry

Let us call the generators of $su(2)$ in the spin $A$ or spin $B$ representation $J^A_i$ and $J^B_i$ respectively. What are the generators of $su(2) \oplus su(2)$ in the $(A, B)$ representation ?

And how do they act on the intertwiners $u_{ab}$ and $v_{ab}$, for a field in the representation $(A, B)$ of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ with particles in the representation of $ISO(2)$ (or its appropriate cover) of helicity $\sigma$ ?

Comment: It appears like you are trying to understand the language of some summary of the [rep theory of the Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group). What in the standard notation WP article I'm linking is still obscure to you?  What text are you struggling to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the WP article Cosmas linked : $$$$

If we call $\mathcal{J}_i$ and $\mathcal{K}_i$ the generators of $su(2) \oplus su(2)$, since : $$J^A_i = \frac{\mathcal{J}_i - i\mathcal{K}_i}{2} \phantom{A}\text{ and }\phantom{A} J^B_i = \frac{\mathcal{J}_i + i\mathcal{K}_i}{2}$$ then $\mathcal{J}_i$ and $\mathcal{K}_i$ are simply given by : $$\mathcal{J}_i = (J^A_i \otimes \mathbf{1} + \mathbf{1} \otimes J^B_i)$$ $$\mathcal{K}_i = i(J^A_i \otimes \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1} \otimes J^B_i)$$ $$$$

And we make them act on the intertwiners $u$ and $v$ by decomposing them on a basis of $su(2) \oplus su(2)$ : $$u_{ab} = \sum_{ab}u_{ab}e_a \otimes f_b$$ and by knowing the action of the $J^A_i$ (resp. $J^B_i$) on the $e_a$ (resp. $f_b$) : \begin{eqnarray}J^A_3e_a &=& ae_a \\ (J^A_1+iJ^A_2)e_a &\propto& e_{a+1} \\ (J^A_1-iJ^A_2)e_a &\propto& e_{a-1}\end{eqnarray}